# RDMA memory semantics for READ/WRITE operations and local memory operations

Tags: rdma

I am seeing unexpected results from RDMA reads that make me doubt my understanding of the RDMA read and write semantics.

I'm trying to implement message passing in RMDA in a manner similar to [L5](https://db.in.tum.de/%7Efent/papers/Low-Latency%20Communication%20for%20Fast%20DBMS%20Using%20RDMA%20and%20Shared%20Memory.pdf), but am running into issues that look like memory tearing. But that shouldn't be happening.

I have a struct that is a bit more complicated than what L5 has:

```
struct Header {
   std::atomic<uint8_t> mailbox = 1;
   std::atomic<uint32_t> length; 
   char data[128];
};
```

On the writing side, I do RDMA reads until I see a value of 1 in mailbox. Then I do an RDMA write of length + data, set mailbox to 0, and send mailbox with a second RDMA write.
On the reading side, I check for mailbox == 0, read the data, and set length to 0 and mailbox to 1.

When I do my RDMA reads I am occasionally seeing lengths <> 0 along with mailbox values of 0. Since RDMA operations are supposed to happen in order, I do not understand how this is happening.

Comment: how are you setting length to 0 and mailbox to 1 on the read side?  if you do separate assignments then there is a window where an RDMA read could see a partial update.

Comment: The length is set to 0, and then the mailbox is set to 1. I understand that could lead to pulling over a length of 0 and a mailbox of 0, but since both are in atomics I thought RDMA would see the writes in the order they are made.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, but you shouldn't rely on ordering of the two RDMA writes when reading locally. The IB specs say that in order to read the result of an RDMA write, you must synchronize through a completion (a subsequent send / write w. immediate) or through an atomic operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible explanation is that if you do an RDMA read targeting a whole `struct Header` then there's no guarantee what order the target RDMA adapter will read from memory to satisfy that read.  Especially since your struct is not aligned to a cacheline size (I'm guessing you're on x86, where cachelines are 64 bytes), so `mailbox` and `length` could be in different cachelines.

I still don't really understand why it's surprising to see a `length` != 0 and `mailbox` == 0 - isn't that the case where the where the reading side hasn't processed the mailbox at all?  From what you wrote, the final state of the struct after the two RDMA writes from the writing side is exactly `length` != 0, `mailbox` == 0.

In any case, since as I described above an RDMA adapter is completely free to read the memory being accessed by RDMA read in any order, it's possible for RDMA read to return any mix of old and new data, no matter what order the CPU updates the fields in.  For example if you had:

1. RDMA read comes in targeting `struct Header`
2. RDMA adapter reads cacheline with `length` field
3. CPU updates `length` to 0 then `mailbox` to 1
4. RDMA adapter reads cacheline with `mailbox` field

then the READ read would fetch `length` != 0, `mailbox` == 1.  This is because the RDMA read operation does not participate in any memory barriers or other ordering, even though you declared your struct members as atomic.